# Forward packets to a transparent proxy server

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, proxy

I'm running Debian 8 and iptables.

Currently I'm able to forward packets to my own server by changing the destination IP on packets with iptables:

```
... DNAT --to-destination MY-IP --persistent
```

But is it possible to preserve the destination IP on the packets and simply forward packages as a sort of proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant "packets", not "packages", then you probably want to use transparent proxying. This can be achieved by moving your iptables rules from *nat* to *mangle* table and using TPROXY target.

From *iptables-extensions(8)* manual:

> TPROXY
>   This  target  is only valid in the mangle table, in the PREROUTING chain and user-defined chains which are only called from this chain. It redirects the packet to a local socket without changing the packet header in any way.
>   It can also change the mark value which can then be used in advanced routing rules.

Comment: Is it something as simple as: `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -j TPROXY --on-ip MY-IP`

Comment: Even simpler - according to the manual, '--on-ip MY-IP' is the default. I only used this a few times some years ago, so I can't help much further. For a transparent web proxy consider using nat/REDIRECT target.

Comment: MY-IP should not be the same server as where my packets originate from, but my proxy-server, so the idea is to put this iptable TPROXY on the server which should send the packets to the proxy server.

Comment: It seems TPROXY requires --to-port, but I want all traffic to be routed to by proxy server...?

Comment: You need to precisely specify what your needs are. To me 'to proxy' and 'by proxy' contradict each other in this case. And I can't see '--to-port' option in the iptables-extensions manual, TPROXY target section. There's '--on-port', but it's explicitly given that '0' can be used as a value, which means 'don't alter port'. So maybe you're mixing TPROXY and REDIRECT?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.
This works, except it alters the destination IP, `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i any -j DNAT --to-destination MY-PROXY-IP`, so something similar without altering the destination IP, but still routes traffic to my proxy server.

Comment: I'm also able to run `ip route add 1.2.3.4/32 via MY-PROXY-IP dev eth1` which then use my proxy server for all ip packets aimed at 1.2.3.4, but I would like to use the proxy server for all ip packets from a specific interface.